# How to run node.js applications locally for development

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, git, backbone.js

I am new to `node.js`,today I joined in another team they are working with `node.js,backbone.js,marionette.js and sqlserver`.I have an idea about `backbone,Marionette` but I never work on `node.js`.They asked me to clone the `git` repository,As per their suggestion I installed `node.js`.

[image]

After cloning the repository,I got the files just in the following way.

[image]

I opened `node_modules` folder,It has nearly 10 sub-folders are there.

[image]

`node-sqlserver` doesn't have any files inside.might be because of that I am getting the following error while server running time.

I ran the server with the following command

```
node server.js local
```

getting the following error

[image]

I don't know,why I am getting.can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe talk to the rest of the team?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all the dependent modules through `npm install`, In your case, you need to install `node-sqlserver`.

`npm install node-sqlserver`

Generally your source code will be having a `package.json`. This file specifies all the 
dependent modules required to run the application, but here this file is missing.